# Weak Self in Blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, weak-references, weak-ptr

Do I need to check if weak self is nil in blocks?

I create weakSelf pointer like:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

and in the beginning of the blocks I do

```
if(!weakSelf){return;}
```

is this unnecessary? or does it depend on whether I coded the rest correctly so that when the self dies, others die too?

Comment: It depends on what your block is supposed to do. In general, if you want to make sure that the block is only executed when wealSelf is not nil than you need that line!

Comment: basically, any method call is a valid operand on `nil` pointer in Obj-C, so it is not necessary to check; like e.g. if the `weakself` is `nil`, then such method call won't cause any issue in your block: `[weakself doSomething];`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That check is unnecessary, and is giving you a false sense of security.

Here's the problem:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (!weakSelf) { return; }
    // THE LINE OF INTEREST
    [weakSelf doSomething];
});
```

At `THE LINE OF INTEREST`, some other thread might clear the last strong reference to `self`, at which point `weakSelf` is set to nil. So the `doSomething` message gets sent to nil, which is “safe” (it does nothing), but might not be what you expected!

It's worse if you want to take a different action when `weakSelf` is nil, e.g.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (weakSelf) {
        [weakSelf doSomething];
    } else {
        [someOtherObject doSomethingElse];
    }
});
```

In this case, between the time the block verifies that `weakSelf` is not nil and the time it sends the `doSomething` message, `weakSelf` might become nil, and neither `doSomething` nor `doSomethingElse` will actually run.

The correct solution is this:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        [strongSelf doSomething];
    } else {
        [someOtherObject doSomethingElse];
    }
});
```

In this case, copying `weakSelf` to `strongSelf` (which is strong by default) is atomic. If `weakSelf` was nil, `strongSelf` will be nil. If `weakSelf` was not nil, `strongSelf` will not be nil, and will be a strong reference to the object, preventing it from being deallocated before the `doSomething` message.

Comment: In your code one can simply use `self` instead of `weakSelf`.

Comment: If you use `self` directly in the block, the block captures `self` strongly, keeping it alive. If you use `weakSelf`, the block doesn't capture `self` strongly, and allows it to be deallocated before the block runs.

Comment: That's correct. So the object simply lives longer. As long as the block needs to be executed. Usually this is exactly what you want.

Comment: But sometimes it's not. The advice to “simply use `self` instead of `weakSelf`” needs to be qualified: sometimes it will change the behavior of the program. Furthermore, in the case when the block is saved indefinitely, it can create a retain cycle. That won't happen in my answer's code, but some commonly-used APIs (like `NSNotificationCenter`) do save the block indefinitely. EralpB didn't show the context in which he creates his block. His use case might need to avoid a retain cycle.

Comment: I did not say with no word: "simply use `self` instead of `weakSelf`."I said: "In *your code* one can simply use self instead of weakSelf". So there is no reason to find examples for something that is not subject of the discussion.

Comment: This example is also a great analogy for understanding `[weak self]` capture within Swift closures. Your correct solution is essentially the same as doing an `if let else` optional chain on `self` within a swift closure.

Answer (score 3):

It seems quite unnecessary since calling a message on nil is a no-op. (Nothing happens)

```
^{
    [weakSelf doSomething]; //Does nothing if weakSelf is nil
}
```

The only reason I can think you might want to do this is if *other* messages (not on self) shouldn't be called

```
^{
    // Here I don't want to add weakSelf as an observer if it's nil
    if (!weakSelf) return;

    [OtherClass addObserverForSomething:weakSelf];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Weak references do not retain the referred object. If none else is retaining it, the object is released and the weak references refers to `nil`.

Therefore it is possible that your code is executed with a `weakSelf` that refers `nil`. But this is no reason to check for it at all. Especially in Objective-C you use a defined behavior, if you send a message `nil`. I. e. it is perfect code, if you set a property using a `nil` reference. It simply goes to nowhere.

Of course sometime you do not want to interact with `nil`. In such a case you have to check for it.

BTW: You need `weakSelf` only in some, rarely circumstances. It is an urban legend that in closures in general references to `self` has to be weak to prevent retain cycles. It has not been true, it is not true and it will never be true.